# Cannot install make on AWS server

Tags: aws

I am trying to install `make`, but I get the error:

```
root@myname:/home/ubuntu/GraphicsMagick-1.3.26# apt-get install make
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
linux-headers-generic : Depends: linux-headers-4.4.0-96-generic but it 
is not going to be installed
linux-image-virtual : Depends: linux-image-4.4.0-96-generic but it is 
not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or 
specify a solution).
```

Before trying the step mentioned above, I tried this:

```
root@myname:/home/ubuntu/GraphicsMagick-1.3.26# make
The program 'make' can be found in the following packages:
 * make
 * make-guile
Try: apt install <selected package>
```

Based on that message, I thought that `make` wasn't installed, therefore leading me here.

Comment: DId you run `sudo apt-get -f install`?

Comment: yes I did that.. after that what should I do?

Comment: when I run `sudo apt-get -f install` I get error: `Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-headers-4.4.0-96_4.4.0-96.119_all.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-headers-4.4.0-96-generic_4.4.0-96.119_amd64.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-4.4.0-96-generic_4.4.0-96.119_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
`

Comment: Run `sudo dpkg --configure -a`

Comment: Error `Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-4.4.0-93-generic
 linux-image-virtual
 linux-virtual
 linux-headers-generic
 linux-headers-virtual
`

Comment: I want to install GraphicsMagick. I am not able to install.. please help

Comment: Please add all the extra information from the comments to your question.  Comments are hard to read and easy to miss.